# Defining adjoint functors: What does "natural bijection" mean?

Tags: category-theory, definition, adjoint-functors

Take the following definition of adjunction from the [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor)

[image]

This definition can be found in numerous other places. My brain parses this definition perfectly up till the point where it says that for every $c$ and $d$ the hom-sets are naturally isomorphic. At his point it does SCRREEETCH, because, as a beginner, learning category theory, natural isomorphisms were only defined *between functors* as a collection of morphisms in the **target category** and not *between collections of morphisms lying in **different** categories.

I know that there are other equivalent definitions of adjunctions, but I don't have the time to go through them to see how to make sense of this definition. I just want a clean explanation how to understand this definition.

Comment: $\text{Hom}_D(L(c),d)$ and $\text{Hom}_C(c,R(d))$ are both *sets*, so they're objects of the category $\text{Set}$, which is the target category where the natural isomorphism is taking place. It's not that the Hom *sets* are naturally isomorphic - there's just a bijection between them, and these bijections cohere to a natural ismorphism between the Hom *functors*.

Comment: The second sentence is just repeating what the first sentence is saying in more basic terms. If you unfold the definition of natural isomorphism you will see this.

Comment: Why does the nlab page say "natural isomorphism" for what has traditionally been called a "natural equivalence"?

Comment: @Rob Arthan natural isomorphism is very standard, to my mind moreso than natural equivalence.

Comment: @KevinCarlson: is it? I use Mac Lane's "Categories for the Working Mathematician" as a primary source for basic category theory notions. If "natural isomorphism" has taken over from "natural equivalence", then do you call "natural transformations" "natural homomorphisms"?

Comment: @RobArthan no, "isomorphism" has a meaning in a general category, whereas "homomorphism" does not. It's a bit awkward to risk equivocating between equivalences and isomorphisms when the two notions are distinct in the category of categories and in other higher categories.

Comment: @Kevin: I should have said "natural homomorphisms or natural morphisms or natural arrows".  Having had a look at nlab, there does seem to have been a terminological shift whereby "natural isomorphism" has supplanted "natural equivalence" and "natural equivalence" has been moved on to a different plane, while "natural transformation" has been left alone. I think the inventors of category theory would have eschewed "natural isomorphism" for precisely the same reason that you eschewed "natural homomorphism".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer, as suggested:

$\text{Hom}_D(L(c),d)$ and $\text{Hom}_C(c,R(d))$ are both sets, i.e.  they're objects of the category $\mathsf{Set}$, which is the target category where the natural isomorphism is taking place.

You wrote:

> My brain parses this definition perfectly up till the point where it says that for every c and d the hom-sets are naturally isomorphic.

It's not that the $\text{Hom}$ *sets* are naturally isomorphic - there's just a bijection between them, and these bijections cohere to a natural ismorphism between the $\text{Hom}$ *functors*.

Comment: Thanks! If you are interested, please see also this question, which I raised as a follow-up to your answer, as one point in it still was unclear to me: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698375/matching-the-definition-of-hom-functor-with-how-these-are-used-when-defining-adj