# Matching the definition of hom-functor with how these are used when defining adjuncts

Tags: category-theory, definition, adjoint-functors

I have a problem matching the definition of a [hom-functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/hom-functor) (from nlab) with how this concept it used in the definition of [adjunction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor) (from nlab):

The hom-functor is defined on $C^{\text{op}}\times C$, but the definition of adjunction requires $C^{\text{op}}\times D$ - and it seems I can't just replace $C$ with $D$ in the definition of a hom-functor, as then the composition "$g \circ q \circ f$" won't work, as $g$ is an arrow from $D$ and $f$ is an arrow from $C$ and composition of arrows between different categories is, as far as I know (just started to learn), undefined.

*[This question came to me after preliminarily understanding the definition of adjunctions, as it was explained in a different [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697783/defining-adjoint-functors-what-does-natural-bijection-mean?noredirect=1#comment3465163_1697783) of mine.*]

Comment: Using a more explicit notation, $F \vdash U : C \to D$ is $\text{Hom}_C \circ (F^{op}\times Id) \cong \text{Hom}_D \circ (Id\times U)$.  $\text{Hom}_C$ still has type $C^{op}\times C \to \mathbf{Set}$, it's only the composition that has type $D^{op}\times C \to \mathbf{Set}$.

Comment: @DerekElkins I'm sorry, I couldn't really follow your answer, as I'm yet a beginner and just learning category theory (what do you mean by "type" ? And what does "$\vdash$" denote ? I'm using this answer to understand the concept of adjunction is I can't us that concept to understand this one.). Could you perhaps explain this more elementary ? Also, don't I need to arrive at a functor $C^{\text{op}} \times D$ instead of $D^{\text{op}} \times C$, i.e. replacing the second $C$ instead of the first ?

Comment: "F⊢U" means F is left adjoint to U.  To say something, say F,  has "type C$\to$ D" means that F is a morphism from C to D in some category, in other words F:C$\to$ D.  Some mathematicians make use of type notation, for example "S:Set" means S is a set (they say "S is of type Set") and "n:Integer" means n is of type integer --or n is an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $L\colon C \to D$ and $R \colon D \to C$ are adjoint if 
$$ \def\h{\mathop{\rm Hom}\nolimits} \h_D\bigl(L(-), -\bigr) \cong \h_C\bigl(-, R(-)\bigr) $$
Now $\h_D$ is a functor $\def\o{\mathrm{op}}D^\o \times D \to \def\S{\mathsf{Set}}\S$, that is the composition with $L$ is a functor $\h_D\bigl(L(-), -\bigr) \colon C^\o \times D \to \S$ ($L$ maps from $C$ to $D$), the right hand side works analogously, we have $\h_C\bigl(-, R(-)\bigr) \colon C^\o \times D \to \S$, as $\h_C \colon C^\o \times C \to \S$.