# Should definition of adjunction include reference to opposite functor?

Tags: category-theory, definition

**Warning:** *This is an incredibly stupid question. [This comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698375/matching-the-definition-of-hom-functor-with-how-these-are-used-when-defining-adj#comment3466133_1698375) seems to address the answer, but I want to make sure since I was not able to find this issue discussed anywhere else, and the comment does not seem to address this question directly.*

The usual definition of adjunction starts with functors $F: D \to C$ and $G: C \to D$, then says that
$$\operatorname{Hom}_C (F(\cdot), X) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_D(\cdot, G(X)) \,, $$
where the equivalence is natural in $X$, and that 
 $$\operatorname{Hom}_C (F(Y), \cdot) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_D(Y, G(\cdot)) \,, $$ where the equivalence is natural in $Y$.

**Question:** Does this make sense strictly speaking? Namely I thought that the contravariant Hom functor
$$\operatorname{Hom}_C(\cdot, X) $$
had "signature" $C^{op}  \to Set$, but the target category of $F$ is $C$, *not* $C^{op}$.

Thus I don't see how $\operatorname{Hom}_C(F(\cdot), X)$ is well-defined, i.e. how can you compose a functor $D \to C$ with one $C^{op} \to Set$ and get a functor $D^{op} \to Set$? Shouldn't the first functor be $D^{op} \to C^{op}$? (E.g. like $F^{op}$.)

So is it (more) correct technically speaking to say that the adjunction conditions (replacing $F$ with $F^{op}$) are:

$$\operatorname{Hom}_C (F^{op}(\cdot), X) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_D(\cdot, G(X)) \,, \quad \text{and} \quad  \operatorname{Hom}_C (F^{op}(Y), \cdot) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_D(Y, G(\cdot)) \,?$$

Comment: Yes this is technically correct but the thing is that you don't have to be 100% formal all of the time in math, just formal enough for the reader to fill in the details themselves easily. As a side note the adjointness condition is equivalently $\text{Hom}_C(F( - ),-) \approx \text{Hom}_D(-,G(-))$ as functors $D^{op} \times C \rightarrow \textbf{Set}$ which is a little more elegant.

Comment: Not distinguishing between functors and their opposites in category theory [is common](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/opposite+category#opposite_functors), because they are defined on the exactly the same data. I agree that this can be a confusing convention.

Comment: Yes, but as @varkov commented, we have $F^{op}(Y)=F(Y)$ and $F^{op}(d)=F(d)$ for any object $Y$ and arrow $d$.

Comment: Another way of addressing this : Think is that there are two "types" of functors from $C$ to $D$. The covariant functors (normal ones), and the contravariant (which reverse arrows) -the contravariant functors are secretely covariant functors from the opposite category, but let's forget about that- Now what you consider is the composition of a covariant functor $C\to D$ with a contravariant functor $D\to \mathbf{Set}$. Here you see that it really is the same $D$. And the total functor is contravariant, since preserving then inverting gives a total of inverting the arrows